# Do different varieties of a given crop require different types of soil?

Tags: soil, food-crops

For example, corn has a lot of varieties, namely varieties A-Z. Is it possible that corn variety A requires a different soil type to grow in than corn variety B? Or is it that this sort of thing is trivial and that all varieties can be grown in the same type of soil?

If possible, I'd like to request references, just for verification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you should consider which variety to choose based on the soil type which is available - different plants simply have different requirements.

`Encyclopedia of Soils in the Environment` might be a good in-depth reference